# Generate Report for Newman/Postman apart from HTML-EXTRA

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner, newman, html-reports-jenkins

I want to generate beautiful HTML reports via Newman/Postman.
Is there any other way apart from HTML or HTML-EXTRA commands?
I want the reports to be like the ones we can generate using selenium or testNG.

Comment: You could always build your own custom reporter and display the data in that way. 

Comment: What is it about those reports that you prefer or would like to see?